# Back to top button doesn't click - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I am trying to achieve the "back to top" feature on a page through simple jquery. The "BACK TO TOP" button appears/disappears as expected.
When it appears if I click on it, I expect it to go to the top of the page, instead nothing happens. I am not sure what's going wrong.

Here's the code:

css:

```
#btoTop {
        padding: 15px 10px;
        background: #1f242a;
        color: #fff;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 15px;
        display: none;
        cursor:pointer;
        cursor:hand;
        width:130px;
        height:40px;
    }
```

html:

```
 <div id='btoTop'>BACK TO TOP</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
                $("#btoTop").fadeIn("slow");
            }
            else {
                $("#btoTop").fadeOut("slow");
            }
        });
        $("#btoTop").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0 },"slow");
        });
});
```

**Note: If I call the click function inside the $(window).scroll(), I am able to click the button. But it flickers and doesn't work well with window resize.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
                $("#btoTop").fadeIn("slow");
            }
            else {
                $("#btoTop").fadeOut("slow");
            }
            $("#btoTop").click(function(event){
              event.preventDefault();
              $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0 },"slow");
            });
        });

});
```

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/042x8sxh/)

Comment: must be something else, I got it to work (https://jsfiddle.net/rp1gzeut/)

Comment: Your code works here: https://jsfiddle.net/y8yqs7oz/

Comment: Specifying pixels doesn't work. The click is not getting called for some wierd reason.

Comment: Wow...how come it doesn't work when I use the exact same code with my application :-(

Comment: will help if you can share your application link, it depends on your html structure as well

Comment: try `z-index` as well, it may be under a transparent element means the button is visible but not clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the button was not yet available in the DOM when I was trying to click it.
Adding a timer on it worked pretty good. Hope this helps someone out there with similar issue...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
                    $("#btoTop").fadeIn("slow");
                }
                else {
                    $("#btoTop").fadeOut("slow");
                }
            });
            $timeout( function() {
                $("#btoTop").click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0 },"slow");
                });
            }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding `click` on your button every single time you scroll, which is unnecessary. You should change it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(window).scroll(function () {

    if( $(window).scrollTop() > 0 ) {

      $("#btoTop").fadeIn("slow");

    } else { 

      $("#btoTop").fadeOut("slow");
    }
  });

  // Bound a single time
  $("#btoTop").click(function ( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Clicked the button");
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0 },"slow");

  });
});
```

This might not be the problem, but should be changed to avoid strange behaviours in your code.

Comment: I am aware of it. Since the single binding of the button is not working, I tried to get the click function inside the scroll. If I do the way you 've mentioned, the click doesnt get called and that's exactly my problem

Comment: @SAM You don't see *"Clicked the button"* in dev tools when you click it? If not then there's a problem elsewhere on the page.

Comment: Yeah ! I dont see the alert coming up. If I place a break point on it, the debugger doesn't even reach it.

Comment: @SAM Are there any other scripts on the page?

Comment: Yes...I have lots of other stuff going on the page. I think I need to dig in more to see what is stopping the button click. However, I suspect if this is the culprit...      $('body').on('click', function(e) {....} which is called in a timeout function. I am not sure though.